# Prevent javascript file load in script block

Tags: javascript, crm

I am working on project in CRM 2015, i have a form and javascript file that was added to it in form properties . When I open the form the javascript file loaded but in script block instead under it's name.Because this issue my Ribbon button not working . I look in some blogs and find that it may be caused because of Ribbon ,but in my case in other from javascript file loaded correctly under it's name and Ribbon button work.
Thanks

Comment: please add some code.

Comment: thank's for reply, but issue is not in code because javascript work fine in case of change events or other events, problem is that in my Ribbon it has  path in commnad="" attribute that contains javascript file name, but when form rendered it load javascript under script block (11) name.

Comment: Im unsure what the question is? You're saying the button is not working, then Ribbon button works. Can you claify. Im guessing the button doesn't work. Prehaps include the JS that was added to the form...

Comment: @Sergey if its not code related this probably isn't the right place to be asking about it

Comment: sorry that I not clear. Button not working. I put break point in function that must work when i click the button and I see that function execution not fired. I thought that maybe problem in javascript file but all work fine when for example I change value of control and validate the value in javascript.

Comment: When you refer your javascript library, you use the "$webresource:MYJavaScript.js"

Answer (score 0):

I find solution to my problem. Problem was that we import managed solution from Dev server to other server. There was some unmanaged customization that overwrite functionality of our Ribbon